Underfull vbox badness
When I use the Springer nature document class in latex, I always encounter the underfull \vbox badness 10000 warning. Following is my test codes:
\documentclass[sn-mathphys-num]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\begin{document}
The online encyclopedia project Wikipedia is the most popular wiki-based website.
\end{document}

Then there is a warning message：underfull vbox badness 10000 warning. Alhtough it doesn't influence the compiling, I really want to know the reason for it.I have tried quiet a lot of solutions suggested online, such as fill the page with more contents, or use flushbottom, or raggedbottom. And since the content don't even include any math theorem environment, or figures, or tables. I can not find the reason for that.

It is hard to help you. It seems to me that sn-jnl is not part of MikTex distro. :-(

Thanks anyway for your careness.

At lines 844-853 you can see in the sn-jnl.cls file
      \def\@evenhead{%
      \vbox to 0pt{\vspace*{-48pt}%
         \hbox to \hsize{\hfill \relax\hfill}}\par%%
      \hspace*{-\textwidth}\hbox to \hsize{\hfill}}%
      \def\@oddhead{%
      \vbox to 0pt{\vspace*{-48pt}%
         \hbox to \hsize{\hfill \relax\hfill}}\par%%

The \@evenhead and \@oddhead create a \vbox to 0pt which includes \vskip-48pt followed by a \hbox. Because the \hbox isn't exactly 48pt height then the \vbox is underfull, because the macro-programmer wants to have its height 0pt. This code is run at each output routine.
I don't know what the code does mean. It seems as some obscure macro programming from my point to view. For example \hbox to \hsize{\hfill \relax\hfill} is absurd. For the sake of my mental health, I didn't look at the next code.
